# AWS EC2 Error: The site can't be reached - ec2.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com took too late to respond. Deploy NodeJS

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I currently have an EC2 instance up and running with Amazon Linux running and transferred my project (which contains both React/NodeJS/Express) onto the EC2 instance via SFTP using FileZilla.

For the EC2's Security Groups, I opened a port for 3000 (protocol: tcp, source: 0.0.0.0/0), which is how my Express is defined as well.

So I sshed into EC2 instance and ran the project's Express, and sees it listening to port 3000 within the terminal. But once I hit the Public DNS with `ec2...us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000`, it says The site can't be reached - ec2...us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com took too late to respond.

What could be the issue and how can I go about from here to connect to it?

Thank you in advance and will upvote/accept answer.

Comment: Can you show some log lines of your Express server start up? What does the output of `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :3000` show? Is your instance located in a public subnet or did you have to access it through a bastion?

Comment: @birryree I simply do `npm run server` inside the project's folder, and I get a log from my project that is is listening to port 3000. Did the command you suggested and got: `tcp 0 0 :: :3000 :::* LISTEN 23569/node`. Sorry but how can I check to see if it is in a public subnet or accessed through bastion? I am simply sshing into it via terminal.

Comment: The `netstat` output looks fine. As for whether or not it's in the public subnet - sounds like it is since you can SSH into it directly. If it weren't on a public subnet, you would not be able to connect to the machine without going through another node (basically, SSHing into another instance and then connecting to your Express application instance through that instance). Have you configured anything else beyond just deploying an app and the security group? Did you set up `iptables`? If you run `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000` locally on the machine, does it work?

Comment: @birryree thanks for the insight! No I have not configured anything else. Should I try the `curl` command once I am sshed into the EC2 instance or just in my regular terminal? Did it while sshed into the EC2 and it just outputs the `.html` file inside the project. But in my regular terminal, it says: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000: Connection refused.`

Comment: Definitely on the instance - sounds like it's responding to you though. On your own computer, you'd have to do `curl http://ec2...us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000` (whatever your public DNS name is). Everything else seems okay, so I'm at a loss as to what else could be the problem other than to double check your instance's security group again.

Comment: The "site took too long to respond" error is usually caused by Network ACL or security group rules. Your security group rules as described look fine, and if you haven't altered the ACLs then the defaults will work for your case, so you should double-check that you've edited the correct security group - the one attached to your EC2 instance.

Alternatively, consider using Elastic Beanstalk to manage the EC2 instance for you.

Comment: @birryree Did it and just got an Operation timed out.

Comment: @LoganPickup Under Inbound tab for Security Group, port 3000 is set for type: Custom TCP rule and Source: custom: 0.0.0.0/0, and Outbound tab just has Type: All traffic, Protocol: All, Port Range: All, and Destination: 0.0.0.0/0. Is it set up correctly?

Comment: @LoganPickup Checking in to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: The security group settings are correct. Since there doesn't seem to be any problem with that, I'd try some troubleshooting steps (in any order): remove your app from the instance and run a simple hello world app; and start up a new instance and try to get it running on that (I'm assuming you haven't changed any VPC settings). If hello world works, it's possible your app is using a resource that works running locally but times out on the EC2 instance.

Comment: @LoginPickup Got it. I'll give that a try. And for the VPC, just to double check, what should I look for specifically?

Comment: How do you serve your express app? Are you using **npm start** or **gulp start** or something like that?

If so, I would look into using something like PM2 or forever to serve your app.

Comment: @LostJon I'm using npm start. Would that be an issue with connecting to `http://ec2...us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000`?

Comment: no, i use the same...but if you cancel your listening service in the terminal or dont run it in the background, you may be killing your app from serving. I know it sounds ridiculous...but i have been stock on the issue of "Damn, i forgot to run "npm start" a few times

Comment: @LostJon Good thing to double check up on. Any other ways to resolve this issue? Still no luck

Comment: well, if you are behind a firewall with limited outbound, make sure to use a proxy. other than that, if you post some code here, we may be able to help you out more.

Comment: @LostJon Absolutely, what code would be helpful? The express and node? And as for the firewall, how can I check if the firewall is causing the issue?

Comment: @LoganPickup I attempted it with a simple hello world app, and even for that I'm being timed out... All I have is simply `var http=require('http'); var port = 9000; http.createServer(function(req, res) { res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); res.end('Hello world!\n');}).listen(port); console.log("Listening on port", port); `. It shows `Listening on port`, but I get timed out again. If possible, could you give rundown as to how to set up instance for Node using Amazon Linux (e.g. sudo yum update)? Possibly I'm missing something.

Comment: @JoKo I don't have the time to go thorugh the steps, but although I've verified it works (running node on EC2), that's not the way I'd do it - I'd run node on Elastic Beanstalk (which is free, by the way - you only pay for the EC2 instances it runs). It will handle setting up security groups, and the NodeJS stack includes node with nginx in front of it as a proxy (so you can access it over the standard http port 80, which means no firewall rules to worry about) - the only thing you have to do is give it a zipped app (no messing around with FTP either!). Much more hassle-free.

Comment: @JoKo a screenshot of your EC2 SecGroup would help, as well as your express code that serves the app on port 3000. If you would like, you can inbox me even more info and I will try on my side...I dont have enought time on my hands to be malicious

Comment: @LostJon Absolutely. Would really appreciate it, but how should I inbox you?

Comment: @LostJon got it! Will email you in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @LostJon Just emailed you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be encountering an issue with outbound traffic. You may be inside a company's network, either physically connected or VPN'd in. In some instances, your VPN isnt set up to handle split traffic, so you must abide by your company's outbound restrictions.

In a situation like this, you would want to use a proxy to access your site. when locking down your security group, make sure you use your proxy's public IP (not your company's).

Answer (score 2):

Just check if your Node.js server is running on the EC2 instance.

Debugging:

1. Check first if It working locally properly.
2. Check for the node.js server in EC2.

   - `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :3000`
3. try to run server with **--verbose** flag i.e `npm run server --verbose`

   - it will show logs of the server while starting.
4. Check for the security group Setting for the EC2 instance.
5. try to connect with the ip:port i.e 35.2.*.*:3000

> If still it not working and response taking long time.
>   that means some other service is running on the same port.

try this in ec2:

```
sudo killall -9 node 
npm run server
```

And connect with using ***IP***(54.4.5.*:3000) or ***public DNS*** (http://ec2...us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000).

Hope It will help :)

Comment: With localhost, it works fine. And then I sshed into EC2, and did `npm run server --verbose`, and it just logged: `npm info it worked if it ends with ok, npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', ...], npm info using npm@3.10.9, npm info using node@v6.9.2, npm verb run-script ['preserve', 'serve', 'postserve'], npm info lifescycle prod_project...`. Then for `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :3000`, I got `tcp 0 0 :: :3000 :::* LISTEN 1071/node`.

Comment: Under Inbound tab for Security Group, port 3000 is set for type: Custom TCP rule and Source: custom: 0.0.0.0/0, and Outbound tab just has Type: All traffic, Protocol: All, Port Range: All, and Destination: 0.0.0.0/0. Is it set up correctly? And 35.2..:3000 just returned `response taking long time`.

Comment: try this 
    
   ``` sudo killall -9 node 
    ``` npm run server

Comment: Tried it but still getting the same response: `response taking long time`.

Comment: Possibly any other options to try out?

Comment: @JoKo sometimes listening to localhost will create trouble in few application. So try putting IP instead of "localhost". Sometimes it do work.

Comment: @roshan I did try `publicIP:3000` yet I'm still getting an error that it's taking too long. You are referring to the `Public IP` under `Description` tab of Instance information, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when we have connectivity issues, it is something basic or a firewall. I assume you have checked whether a firewall is running on either end, eg. iptables -L -n. Also, any protocol analyzer like wireshark or tcpdump would tell you where packets to port 3000 are visible.

Comment: I have not checked yet, but would doing `iptables -L -n`, tell me? Also could you elaborate on knowing where packets to port 3000 are visible mean?

Comment: Firewall is implemented with iptables entries. Packets can get lost ANYWHERE between your 2 endpoints. Knowing that the packets got to the far end discards half the path as suspect. It's what we do day in and day out.

Comment: Got it. So how can I test them out?