# Docker container inside AWS not accessible from outside

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I am running a REST service as docker container on an EC2 instance in public subnet of a VPC. I can access the endpoints from within the ec2 container but unable to access from outside.

I have verified that the Security Group has ALL TRAFFIC enabled for Anywhere
Also, NACL has rule to allow INBOUND and OUTBOUND traffic from anywhere
Route table associated to the subnet has route to internet gateway

Any suggestions

Comment: How did you map the host to the container?

Comment: Container firewall, maybe?

Comment: I started the container using docker run command:
docker run -p 8080:8080 myImageName:latest
That way, the host port is mapped to container port

Regarding container firewall, i checked the security group attached to EC2 instance and it is allowing all traffic at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, it was caused as i was connected to my company's VPN. When i disconnected from vpn i was able to access the endpoint successfully.

Thanks to the suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41623380/16612893